# SpEL are not read in @Query after Spring Boot 2.0.0 M7 update

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-el

I had my Spring Boot 2.0.0 M3 application developed. Everything worked just fine. But after updating to Spring Boot 2.0.0 M7 (or even to Spring Boot 2.0.0 M5 more recently) `SpEL`s in my `@Query` are not longer compiled properly. For example

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM com.mypackage.models.Model m WHERE m.status IN 
(:#{T(com.mypackage.utils.Constants).SPECIAL_STATUSES})")
public List<Model> findModelWithSpecialStatuses();
```

And I get the following exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown parameter name : __$synthetic$__1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter name : __$synthetic$__1
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter name : __$synthetic$__1
at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:486) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.setParameter(QueryParameterSetter.java:99) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.lambda$bind$0(ParameterBinder.java:57) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1080) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:57) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateCountQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:108) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createCountQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:228) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.count(JpaQueryExecution.java:199) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.lambda$doExecute$0(JpaQueryExecution.java:193) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.support.PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(PageableExecutionUtils.java:62) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:192) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:127) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:597) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:580) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
... 115 common frames omitted
```

`(:#{T(com.mypackage.utils.Constants).SPECIAL_STATUSES})` - is a `List` of `Object`s

Comment: If it worked before this sounds like a regression. Please file a bug at jira.spring.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that `Hibernate` in newer versions of `Spring Boot` optimizes its queries, so some of parameters are not visible anymore. The fastest solution I found was simply checking those parameters for `not null` in my `@Query`